# Is there a way to "uncheck" songs on my iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I have many audiobooks in my itunes, some of which are in their appropriate place, but some of which are categorized as songs. I've moved them all to playlists and unchecked them in itunes so that they do not play on my computer, but they still appear in my songs on the iphone, so that when I shuffle my songs, I often get random book chapters. It's not a huge deal (I just skip them), but it is annoying, especially when I'm driving. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

1. Select an Audiobook file in your library that has been categorised as a song.
2. Right click on it and select “Get Info.”
3. Open the Options tab.
4. In the “Media Kind” field, select Audiobook.

These files will no longer appear in the Music library. To see them again, open the Books library.